# Why is Mathematica's integral from negative infinity to positive infinity of the normal distribution probability density function not 1?

Tags: numerical-integration, distributions

As we know, the integral from negative infinity to positive infinity of the normal distribution probability density function is 1. However, in Mathematica, it only returns
$\frac{1}{2} \text{erf}\left(\frac{x-\mu }{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)$. Why doesn't Mathematica return 1?

```
Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], x], x]
```

[image]

Comment: `Assuming[σ ∈ PositiveReals  , Integrate[   Evaluate@PDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ],x], {x, -∞, ∞}]]`

Comment: @Syed `NormalDistribution` should have the definition like `σ ∈ PositiveReals`. And `Integrate[,x]` should have define the indefinite integral.

Comment: Mathematica assumes that all symbols are complex unless resolved.

Comment: @Syed But **normal distribution probability density function** assums that `σ ∈ PositiveReals`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**THIS IS AN EXTENDED COMMENT RATHER THAN AN ANSWER**

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Re : "But normal distribution probability density function assums that σ ∈ PositiveReals"

The built-in probability distributions are given the required assumptions when defined and the built-in statistical functions (e.g., [`Mean`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html), [`Variance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variance.html), [`Moment`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Moment.html)) make use of these assumptions, but these assumptions are not more broadly used (e.g., not automatically used by [`Integrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) even though it uses the option [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html)). The assumptions are accessed with [`DistributionParameterAssumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionParameterAssumptions.html), e.g.,

```
DistributionParameterAssumptions[NormalDistribution[m, s]]

(* m ∈ Reals && s > 0 *)
```

With a user-defined distribution

```
myNormal[m_, s_] = 
 ProbabilityDistribution[
  PDF[NormalDistribution[m, s], x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

[image]

However, even though this distribution was built from [`NormalDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NormalDistribution.html), since no assumptions were given when `myNormal` was defined

```
DistributionParameterAssumptions[myNormal[m, s]]

(* True *)

#[myNormal[m, s]] & /@ {Mean, Variance, Moment[#, 1] &}
```

[image]

However, when `Assumptions` are given when the distribution is defined

```
myNormal2[m_, s_] = ProbabilityDistribution[1/(E^((x - m)^2/(2*s^2))*
          (Sqrt[2*Pi]*s)), {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
   Assumptions -> Element[m, Reals] && s > 0];

#[myNormal2[m, s]] & /@ {Mean, Variance, Moment[#, 1] &}

(* {m, s^2, m} *)
```

While these functions automatically make use of `DistributionParameterAssumptions`, `Integrate` does not

```
Integrate[PDF[myNormal2[m, s], x], {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

[image]

Compare with

```
Assuming[DistributionParameterAssumptions[myNormal2[m, s]],
 Integrate[PDF[myNormal2[m, s], x], {x, -∞, ∞}]]

(* 1 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
r = Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], x], {x, -Infinity,Infinity}];
Assuming[σ > 0, Simplify[r]]
```

Gives

```
(* 1 *)
```

Comment: But, `Integrate` assums indefinite integral. Why should we use `{x, -Infinity,Infinity}` here?